# Is it possible to pass livedata value to the global variable?

Tags: android, android-livedata

I have livedata observer and I want to get value of that observer to the global list. Is this possible?

```
private List<User> getUsers = new ArrayList<>();

dailyFragmentViewModel.getAllUsers().observe(getActivity(), new Observer<List<User>>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(List<User> users) {
            getUsers = users;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Fragments should be using `getViewLifecycleOwner()` as the lifecycle owner, not their enclosing Activity.